# filter strings from nested dictionaries (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I have nested dictionaries, in which I am trying to filter out the strings of `svgs`. Here's my toy version.

```
dat = {"objects": [{"svg": "abcd"}, 
  {"svg": "efgh"}, 
  {"svg": "ijkl"}, 
  {"svg": "mnop"}, 
  {"svg": "qrst"}]}
```

I'm not sure if `filter` is the correct function, but I am currently trying something like this:

```
var allSVGs = _.filter(dat, {'objects': 'svg'});
console.log(allSVGs, 'allSVGs');
```

I hope to end up with an array of strings:

```
allSVGs = ["abcd", "efgh", "ijkl", "mnop", "qrst"]
```

Any help or advice would really be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing in JS as `{"abcd"}`, did you meant to have an array of strings? `["abcd", "efgh"]`

Comment: Thank you @aldokkani! Yes, I'm new coding so that is what I meant. I've edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the structure you want `[{"abcd"}, {"efgh"}, {"ijkl"}, {"mnop"}, {"qrst"}]`  this is not correct. For an Object `{}` there should be key and value pair.

but you can try

```js
var data = { "objects": [
      {"svg": "abcd"}, 
      {"svg": "efgh"}, 
      {"svg": "ijkl"}, 
      {"svg": "mnop"}, 
      {"svg": "qrst"}
    ]
};
    
var result = data.objects.map(el => el.svg);
console.log(result);
```

this will results into `["abcd", "efgh", "ijkl", "mnop", "qrst"]`